# Como obtener el codigo de salida que arroja un exe ejecutado desde java con runtime?

Tags: java, exe

Ejecuto un archivo `.exe` (para envio de imagenes) desde `java` el cual puede tirar diferentes codigos de salida dependiendo de el error, esta es mi clase:

```
public static int SendImg(String ip, int puerto, String rutaIMG, String tipo) {
        Process p = null;
        try {
            Runtime aplicacion = Runtime.getRuntime();
            p = aplicacion.exec("C:\\SendImg.exe " + ip + " " + puerto + " " + '"' + rutaIMG + '"' + " " + tipo);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return p.exitValue();
        }
        return p.exitValue();
    }
```

y asi la llamo, el problema es que siempre me devuelve `0` independientemente de si fallo o no la transferencia:

```
int res = Conector.SendImg(cIP.getSelectedItem().toString(), puerto, tRuta.getText(), cbTipo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        if (res == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Imagen enviada correctamente");
        }
        if (res == 1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error enviando imagen producto  A");
        }

        if (res == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error enviando imagen producto B");
        }

        if (res == 3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error enviando imagen Splash");
        }
        if (res == 6) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parametro no valido sTypeData");
        }
        if (res == 7) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe la imagen");
        }
```

Si es correcto, la imagen se envia, si no lo esta, la imagen no se envia pero igualmente obtengo cero, hay alguna otra manera para obtener el codigo de salida?

**EDICION:**
archivo ZIP con el ejecutable; [SendImg.exe](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B59mJcnu1FzxSUQxWmgxSkJ4NDA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método [`java.lang.Process.waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) hace que el hilo actual espere, si es necesario, hasta que el proceso representado por este objeto de proceso haya finalizado. Este método devuelve inmediatamente si el subproceso ya ha finalizado, si el subproceso aún no se ha terminado, el hilo llamante se bloqueará hasta que se cierre el subproceso.

Con lo antes mencionado, el valor asignado a tu variable `res` es el resultado devuelto del método `p.waitFor();`, ejemplo:

```
 try {
        // crea nuevo proceso
        System.out.println("Creando Proceso...");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");

        System.out.println("Esperando....");
        // obtiene numero de systemcode
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Ejecución normal :

```
Creando Proceso...
Esperando....
Process exitValue: 0
```

Ejecución finalizada mediante administrador de tareas:

```
Creando Proceso...
Esperando....
Process exitValue: 1
```

Comment: de antemano muchas gracias por la respuesta, el .exe es el que devuelve 6 tipos de salida; `0,1,2,3,6,7` son esos que arroja a los que quiero obtener acceso, intente esto, me sigue tirando `0` ya que se ejecuta correctamente el proceso pero no puedo acceder a los codigos de salida del exe (ejemplo cuando le paso una ruta de imagen falsa `exit 7`)

Comment: Hola, entiendo, tu de hace un return y quieres cachar eso, ahorita estoy desde el móvil, da un vistazo a esta respuesta, agrega el inputStream. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196619/println-the-return-values-of-an-executable